# ASP.NET Working with normalized database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

First of all sorry for what may seem as dumb question, but I have zero experience in that area. 
So at work I was given a database (which is way more normalized than needed) and for each Insert/update/delete/select I have a separate stored procedure.

As someone with zero experience I started creating my own stored procedures and displaying text instead of ID and it was all going well until I realized I have to update this records at some point :). 
So my question is can you give me directions on how to display "eye-friendly" information in the GridView and at the same time be able to edit/update this information?

Currently what I am doing is just calling a stored procedure and databind the grid view to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study time! I would like to explain this to You directly, but it is much more useful to already made tutorials, which have needed information. And this topic would be so rich, it would be hard to explain in just few sentences/examples.

The best option is to use tools/classes that .NET provides to You. Among them there is DataSet, which will incredibly help You out with all set of modifications deletes/selects.

You can bind `DataSource` to `GridView`, which will autofill data and You can just allow some kind of modifications to it.

Other approach is to use EntityFramework, where You can modify data in ways You want - it will do a lot of work for You.

Latest topic You should be interested in is LINQ - simple get data & do some queries/modifications in Your app (not at SQL server).

Check links below:

[What is ADO.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471198/what-is-ado-net)

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx

Also recommending [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zAXVvxdt3o), be careful about video/sounds quality. Try some other videos with similar name.

http://tutorialspoint.com/linq/